# Haskell group function / First element always missing

Tags: haskell, grouping

I want to write a function called group that takes a list of type `[a]` and returns a a list of list of type `[[a]]` containing identical characters. Here is a simple example of the expected behaviour:

`group [1,1,2,1,3,3,3]` ⇒+ `[[1,1],[2],[1],[3,3,3]]`

`group "aaabbcdddd"` ⇒+ `["aaa","bb","c","dddd"]`

I wrote the following code but the problem is that this code always misses the first element from the original list

```
group [] = []
group (x:xs) = groupHelper xs x []

groupHelper :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
groupHelper [] prev fs = fs
groupHelper (x:xs) prev [] = groupHelper xs prev [[x]]
groupHelper (x:xs) prev fs = if (x == prev) then groupHelper (xs) (x) ((init fs) ++ [(last(fs)++[x])]) 
     else groupHelper (xs) x (fs++[[x]])
```

The code would produce the following output for this input.

`group [1,1,2,1,3,3,3]` ⇒+ `[[1],[2],[1],[3,3,3]]`

=> Here a 1 at the beginning of the first list would be missing

---

`group "aaabbcdddd"` ⇒+ `["aa","bb","c","dddd"]`

=> Here one `'a'` at the beginning of the first list would be missing

I hope someone can help me to solve this bug. Thank you very much

Comment: Btw i found a solution to the problem - if I call **group (x:xs) = groupHelper xs x [[x]]** it returns the correct result. But I still don't exactly understand why I did the wrong thing without this modification

Comment: BTW, recursively building up lists like `f ... = f (...) ++ (...)` is very bad for performance, because you append over and over to the right, and each time this requires traversing a bigger and bigger list. Better is to cons the partial result to the _left_ of the recursive call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call groupHelper the first time (from group) you’re passing the prev arg, but the helper uses it only for comparison.
Solution could be to add the fist item as the first element of the first group on first call.
Like this:
`group (x:xs) = groupHelper xs x [[x]]`

Comment: This was a pretty stupid mistake of me. I solved it now by writing **group (x:xs) = groupHelper (x:xs) x []** because I think it is a little bit cleaner than the previous solution. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the first element `x` to the accumulator, so you can fix this with:

```
group (x:xs) = groupHelper xs x [[x]]
```

That being said, the grouping is not done very efficient: you each time add at the end of the list. This will make it an *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* algorithm. Furthermore it is not that lazy either: it will require a lot of evaluation, if you are only interested in, for example, the first group.

We can make a more lazy and efficient implementation with:

```
group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
group [] = []
group (x:xs) = let (y:ys) = go xs x in (x:y):ys
    where go [] _ = [[]]
          go (a:as) b | a == b = let (c:cs) = go as b in (a:c):cs
                      | otherwise = [] : go (a:as) a
```